# Reconnect serial port in Java without user interaction

Tags: java, connection, serial-port, arduino

I am writing a java program using serial data.  I am curious to how I could solve a problem where my arduino gets disconnected, therefore stopping serial data, and then getting connected again to which it will start sending data again without any human interaction.

```
public void initialize() {
    working = 1;
    CommPortIdentifier portId = null;
    Enumeration portEnum = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
        CommPortIdentifier currPortId = (CommPortIdentifier) portEnum.nextElement();
        for (String portName : PORT_NAMES) {
            if (currPortId.getName().equals(portName)) {
                portId = currPortId;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (portId == null) {
        thirdDC = "Could not find COM Port. Error";
        System.out.println(thirdDC);

        return;
    }

    try {

        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open(this.getClass().getName(),
                TIME_OUT);

        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(DATA_RATE,
                SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
        output = serialPort.getOutputStream();


        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        System.out.println("WORKING");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString() + "NOPE");


    }
}


public synchronized void close() {
    if (serialPort != null) {
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        serialPort.close();
    }
}




public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
    String stop = "ERROR";

    if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        serialI = true;
        try {

            inputLine=input.readLine();
            if (inputLine.equals(y)){
                System.out.println(y);
                temp1 = "OFF";
                value = 0;
            }
            if (inputLine.equals(z)){
                System.out.println(z);
                temp1 = "ON";
                value = 0;
            }
            if (inputLine.equals(stop)){
                System.out.println(stop);
                temp = "ERROR";
                value = 1;  
            }


            x = Double.parseDouble(inputLine);
            if (x > 0){
            temp = inputLine;
            System.out.println(x);
            value = 0;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) { 


        }

    }else{
    }
}
```

The code above are the methods I think need to get edited.  So my question is, when I unplug my USB cord, how can I close the serial port at the same time?  Then when I plug the USB cord back in, how can my program recognize it was plugged in again and being communicating serially?

Comment: So what's the question? How to write a loop with a retry in it?

Comment: @EJP, I edited the post again.  But yes the first part of my question would be how I could create a message letting the user of the program know if the USB becomes unplugged, then if it becomes plugged back in, the message goes away and the program continues as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 1):

When you disconnect the arduino you should be ending up with a runtime exception you can handle in whatever way you see fit. Find where that exception is thrown, change public void initialize to public boolean initialize that returns true when a connection is made. When handling the exception continue to call initialize until it returns true. That's just one way of doing it.